# Is there a way to set one background that ignores the page breaks within this full page pure javascript site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
/**
 * Full page
 */
(function () {
 'use strict';
 
 /**
  * Full scroll main function
  */
 var fullScroll = function (params) {
  /**
   * Main div
   * @type {Object}
   */
  var main = document.getElementById(params.mainElement);
  
  /**
   * Sections divclass
   * @type {Array}
   */
  var sections = main.getElementsByTagName('section');
  
  /**
   * Full page scroll configurations
   * @type {Object}
   */
  var defaults = {
   container : main,
   sections : sections,
   animateTime : params.animateTime || 0.7,
   animateFunction : params.animateFunction || 'ease',
   maxPosition: sections.length - 1,
   currentPosition: 0,
   displayDots: typeof params.displayDots != 'undefined' ? params.displayDots : true,
   dotsPosition: params.dotsPosition || 'left'
  };

  this.defaults = defaults;
  /**
   * Init build
   */
  this.init();
 };

 /**
  * Init plugin
  */
 fullScroll.prototype.init = function () {
  this.buildPublicFunctions()
   .buildSections()
   .buildDots()
   .addEvents();

  var anchor = location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/')[0];
  location.hash = 0;
  this.changeCurrentPosition(anchor);
  this.registerIeTags();
 };

 /**
  * Build sections
  * @return {Object} this(fullScroll)
  */
 fullScroll.prototype.buildSections = function () {
  var sections = this.defaults.sections;
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
   sections[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
  }
  return this;
 };

 /**
  * Build dots navigation
  * @return {Object} this (fullScroll)
  */
 fullScroll.prototype.buildDots = function () {  
  this.ul = document.createElement('ul');
  
  this.ul.className = this.updateClass(1, 'dots', this.ul.className);
  this.ul.className = this.updateClass(1, this.defaults.dotsPosition == 'right' ? 'dots-right' : 'dots-left', this.ul.className);

  var _self = this;
  var sections = this.defaults.sections;  

  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
   var li = document.createElement('li');
   var a = document.createElement('a');
  
   a.setAttribute('href', '#' + i);   
   li.appendChild(a);
   _self.ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  this.ul.childNodes[0].firstChild.className = this.updateClass(1, 'active', this.ul.childNodes[0].firstChild.className);

  if (this.defaults.displayDots) {
   document.body.appendChild(this.ul);
  }

  return this;
 };

 /**
  * Add Events
  * @return {Object} this(fullScroll)
  */
 fullScroll.prototype.addEvents = function () {
  
  if (document.addEventListener) {
   document.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.addEventListener('wheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.addEventListener('keyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart, false);
   document.addEventListener('touchend', this.touchEnd, false);
   window.addEventListener("hashchange", this.hashChange, false);

   /**
    * Enable scroll if decive don't have touch support
    */
   if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    if(!('ontouchstart' in window)){
     document.body.style = "overflow: scroll;";
     document.documentElement.style = "overflow: scroll;";
    }
   }   

  } else {
   document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.attachEvent('onkeyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
  }
  
  return this;
 }; 

 /**
  * Build public functions
  * @return {[type]} [description]
  */
 fullScroll.prototype.buildPublicFunctions = function () {
  var mTouchStart = 0;
  var mTouchEnd = 0;
  var _self = this;

  this.mouseWheelAndKey = function (event) {
   if (event.deltaY > 0 || event.keyCode == 40) { 
    _self.defaults.currentPosition ++;
    _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.currentPosition);    
   } else if (event.deltaY < 0 || event.keyCode == 38) {
    _self.defaults.currentPosition --;
    _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.currentPosition); 
   }
   _self.removeEvents();
  };

  this.touchStart = function (event) {
   mTouchStart = parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
   mTouchEnd = 0;
  };

  this.touchEnd = function (event) {
   mTouchEnd = parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
   if (mTouchEnd - mTouchStart > 100 || mTouchStart - mTouchEnd > 100) {
    if (mTouchEnd > mTouchStart) {
     _self.defaults.currentPosition --;
    } else {
     _self.defaults.currentPosition ++;     
    }
    _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.currentPosition);
   }   
  };

  this.hashChange = function (event) {
   if (location) {
    var anchor = location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/')[0];
    if (anchor !== "") {
     if (anchor < 0) {
      _self.changeCurrentPosition(0);
     } else if (anchor > _self.defaults.maxPosition) {
      _self.changeCurrentPosition(_self.defaults.maxPosition);
     } else {
      _self.defaults.currentPosition = anchor;
      _self.animateScroll();
     }     
    }    
   }
  };

  this.removeEvents = function () {
   if (document.addEventListener) {
   document.removeEventListener('mousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.removeEventListener('wheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   document.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.touchStart, false);
   document.removeEventListener('touchend', this.touchEnd, false);

   } else {
    document.detachEvent('onmousewheel', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
    document.detachEvent('onkeyup', this.mouseWheelAndKey, false);
   }

   setTimeout(function(){
    _self.addEvents();
   }, 600);
  };

  this.animateScroll = function () {
   var animateTime = this.defaults.animateTime;
   var animateFunction = this.defaults.animateFunction;
   var position = this.defaults.currentPosition * 100;

   this.defaults.container.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(-' + position + '%)';
   this.defaults.container.style.mozTransform = 'translateY(-' + position + '%)';
   this.defaults.container.style.msTransform = 'translateY(-' + position + '%)';
   this.defaults.container.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + position + '%)';
   this.defaults.container.style.webkitTransition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;
   this.defaults.container.style.mozTransition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;
   this.defaults.container.style.msTransition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;
   this.defaults.container.style.transition = 'all ' + animateTime + 's ' + animateFunction;

   for (var i = 0; i < this.ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
     this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className = this.updateClass(2, 'active', this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className);
     if (i == this.defaults.currentPosition) {
     this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className = this.updateClass(1, 'active', this.ul.childNodes[i].firstChild.className);
    }
   }
  };

  this.changeCurrentPosition = function (position) {
   if (position !== "") {
    _self.defaults.currentPosition = position;
    location.hash = _self.defaults.currentPosition;
   }
  };

  this.registerIeTags = function () {
   document.createElement('section'); 
  };

  this.updateClass = function (type, newClass, currentClass) {
   if (type == 1) {
    return currentClass += ' ' + newClass;
   } else if (type == 2) {
    return currentClass.replace(newClass, '');
   }
  };

  return this;
 };
 window.fullScroll = fullScroll;
})();
```

```css
body, html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.scroll-container section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.dots { 
 z-index: 1;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.dots li a {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 4px;
 height: 5px;
 display: block;
}

.dots li a:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -ms-border-radius: 10px;
 -o-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px; 
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.dots li a.active:before {
 content: '';
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
 margin-top: -4px;
 left: 7px; 
 background-color: white;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
 -o-transform: scale(1.0);
 transform: scale(1.0);
}

.dots-right {
 right: 10px;
}

.dots-left {
 left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Full page scroll</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet/full-page-scroll.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <style type="text/css">
 .section1 {
  background-color: #7DBCD4;
 }

 .section2 {
  background-color: #98C19F; 
 }

 .section3 {
  background-color:  #A199E2;
 }

 .section4 {
  background-color:  #CC938E;
 }

 .section5 {
  background-color:  #D2C598;
 }
   
 section div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;  
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

 span {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .button {
  background-color: #F2CF66;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
  padding: 10px 40px;     
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none; 
 }
 </style> 
</head>
<body>
 <a href="https://github.com/almeida-matheus/fullPageScrollPureJS">
  <img style="position: fixed;z-index:99; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub">
 </a>
 <div id="main" class="scroll-container">
  <section class="section1">
   <div>
    <span>It's beautiful and don't need Jquery :D</span>     
   </div>
   <div>
    <a href="#" class="button">Download here</a>
   </div> 
  </section>
  <section class="section2">
   <div>
    <span>Working on Tablets and Phones</span>    
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section3">
   <div>
    <span>Anuncie aqui</span>    
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section4">
   <div>
    <span>Funciona até no IE!</span>    
   </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section5">
   <div>
    <span>Chegar de falar, é só baixar!</span>    
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
 <script src="assets/javascript/full-page-scroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  new fullScroll({
   mainElement: 'main',
   displayDots: true,
   dotsPosition: 'left',
   animateTime: 0.7,
   animateFunction: 'ease'
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this one page website that has 5 sections. I would like to make the background color a gradient like an ocean. Light blue at the top, deep dark blue at the bottom.

Here is the gradient background: rgb(62,75,107);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(62,75,107,1) 12%, rgba(51,94,198,1) 20%, rgba(45,105,253,1) 23%, rgba(45,105,253,1) 35%, rgba(45,105,253,1) 44%, rgba(45,105,253,1) 46%, rgba(75,137,194,1) 57%, rgba(47,170,195,1) 71%, rgba(64,179,185,1) 79%, rgba(34,186,195,1) 84%, rgba(203,222,223,1) 92%);

My issue is that I can only set each square of the 1 page site to that gradient. Which is then just repeating gradients. I want one over smooth gradient background. How can I override each separate background, but still keep the page breaks?

Here is the one page site: https://www.cssscript.com/cross-platform-smooth-one-page-scrolling-pure-javascript/

Comment: Please include all relevant HTML and CSS in a Stack Snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry about that. That should be all of the code. Thanks!